# Inverse $z$-transform similar to convolution

Tags: convolution, integral-transforms, z-transform

I know that
$$ \mathcal{Z} \left\lbrace x_1[n] * x_2[n] \right\rbrace = X_1(z) X_2(z).$$

But what would $$ X_1(z+a) X_2(z+a) $$ be equal to in terms of $ x_1[n] $ and $ x_2[n] $? i.e. what does frequency-shifting do to the signals in this case?

I have that
\begin{align}
X_1(z+a)X_2(z+a) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left [\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} x_1(l)x_2(n-l) \right ](z+a)^{-n}\\
                 &= \mathcal{Z} \left \{ ? \right \} \\
\end{align}
but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hi! Would you mind giving the source of the last relation you showed? I got really interested in your question! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bertozzijr From the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties -- taking the second line in the row for "convolution" in the table, I simply made the substitution $ z \to z + a $.

Comment: yes, yes, of course, thanks! sorry for my momentary dumbness, haha!